# C# check/uncheck checkbox in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

This is my code:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").SetAttribute("value", txtUsername.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", txtPassword.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rememberme").SetAttribute("checked", cbAutoLogin.Checked.ToString());
```

The username and password is ok I don't have any problem, but the check is not working. The problem is not on the cbAutoLogin.Checked.ToString(), even if I write true or false nothing change.

Here is the checkbox on html

```
<input type='checkbox' id='rememberme' checked='checked' name='rememberme' value='1' class='input_check' />
```

Anyone else have the same problem? Or I do something wrong?

Comment: First thing I see is that you need to add runat="server" in the input element

Comment: @astroboy WinForms :-) Title caught me off guard too.

Comment: @pst. Whoops. I should read the whole question plus the tags next time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rememberme").InvokeMember("CLICK");
```

It will make it checked if unchecked and Unchecked if Checked.

OR change the value attribute same like username,password to 0 or 1.